# Calling Methods from Inherited Class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module, singleton

I have the following classes:

Module

```
module AlertService
    module MessageTemplate
      def generate_message
        "test"
      end
    end
  end
```

Parent class:

```
module Client
  def post uri, params={}
    Net::HTTP.post_form uri, params
  end
end

module AlertService
  class BaseAlert
    extend MessageTemplate
    include Singleton
    include Client
    def initialize; end
  end
end
```

Child Class:

```
module AlertService
class TestAlert < BaseAlert
  include Singleton
  def initialize
  options = {
    username: "Screen Alert Bot",
    http_client: Client
  }
  @notifier = Slack::Notifier.new(rails.config.url, options)
  end

  def self.create_message
    message = generate_message
  end

  def self.send_message
    create_message
    @notifier.post blocks: message
  end
end
end
```

I can create the test alert like this: `s= AlertService::TestAlert`

But I get the error when I do this:

s.send_message

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `generate_message' for AlertService::TestAlert::Class
```

generate_message is a method from the MessageTemplate module included in the BaseAlert class. Why is it saying my inherited class doesn't have access to the method?

Comment: What is `generate_message`? It's not listed in your code here.

Comment: @tadman it's a method from the module MessageTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `Singleton` correctly. You're including it, but then not using it, instead bypassing that altogether and calling class methods that have nothing to do with Singleton. They're in turn calling class methods on the parent class that don't exist.

The solution is to use `Singleton` as intended:

```
module AlertService
  class BaseAlert
    include MessageTemplate
    include Singleton

    def initialize
    end
  end
end

module AlertService
  class TestAlert < BaseAlert
    def initialize
      @notifier = Slack::Notifier.new(Rails.configuration.url, Rails.configuration.options)
    end

    def create_message
      message = generate_message
    end

    def send_message
      create_message
      @notifier.post blocks: message
    end
  end
end
```

Where now you [call with `instance` as documented](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html):

```
AlertService::TestAlert.instance.send_message
```

Comment: the format makes sense. I'm still getting an error for the method, generate_message NoMethodError: undefined method `generate_section_description'. This is a method from the module, i'm not sure why I can't call it

Comment: Are you sure it's an instance method and not a class method? Also if you need it in `BaseAlert` move the `include` into that class. I've updated the code here.

Comment: i'll double check my code, I also included the module in the example

Comment: generate_message is the module's method. I was hoping I could just call it in the TestAlert since MessageTemplate is included in the BaseAlert

Comment: In your original code it's not included in the right place. You include it in the `AlertService` module, not the class.

Comment: good call. I updated it and just tested it, I'm still getting the error of undefined method

Comment: Check that the method actually exists first, like `AlertService::TestAlert.instance_methods`.

Comment: oh, i was using extend instead of include! Thanks! One more question, do you the proper way to reference the Client module? (I updated the code for reference) It's an option for initiating the notifier but the class doesnt look like its recognizing the module

Comment: If it's a top-level module, then just `Client` is fine, or `::Client` if there's another module in the hierarchy with the same name, but only if. Using `::Client` implies there's another to avoid ambiguity, which can be confusing if there isn't.